# Acess files in google drive/dropbox using python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, dropbox, urllib, mechanize-python

Is it possible to access say a text file that I've placed in these storage accounts and use them as regular files?. I've tried with mechanize and urllib, but I'm not able to succeed. I'm not interested in using the API's because of the limitations that it may impose. Could someone suggest a way for this, or atleast a way to access the account via ftp or other methods. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For google Drive there is a very good API-Documentation:

Google Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python

Dropbox API: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python

I've tested the GDrive API by myselfe, and it works like a charm, i can' say anything about Dropbox API, but shouldn't be much different.

If you mean with **Limitations** access Limitations google Drives Limitations are

10.000.000 Requests/Day

10 Request/Second/User

Comment: Is there any limitations using the api?

Comment: i've edited my post with the request limitations, i don't know of any other limitation